# How can I join all the record obtained by a select on a table with the records of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, rdbms

I am pretty new in SQL and I have the following problem trying to implement the following query on a **MySql** database.

So I have this situation:

Into my database have a table named **TID023_INTERVENTO** where each line of this table represent a **project** (for me a project is something that can receive a grant).

And it have the following structure:

```
Field            Type            Null   Key    Default    Extra

PRG_INT          int(11)         NO     PRI               auto_increment
COD_INT          varchar(15)     NO     UNI     
DES_INT          text            YES            
COD_CUP          varchar(15)     YES    UNI     
FLG_CUP_PRO      tinyint(1)      YES            
...................................................................
...................................................................
...................................................................
```

So by this query:

```
select * from TID023_INTERVENTO where COD_TIP_STA_INT = 2 && COD_TIP_BAN = 2;
```

I obtain a list of projects (a project is a record of the **TID023_INTERVENTO** table) that have 2 specific values for the **COD_TIP_STA_INT** and **COD_TIP_BAN** fields.

Ok, this query works fine and I obtain my list of projects.

My problem is that now I have to modify the previous query to join the information stored into another table named **TID031_PIANO**.

The situation is the following: each record retrieved by the previous query is linked 1:1 to a record into the **TID031_PIANO** table that have the following structure:

```
Field             Type          Null    Key
PRG_PIA           int(11)       NO      PRI
DES_DEN_SCU       varchar(255)  NO  
DES_PIA           text          YES 
PRG_INT           int(11)       YES     MUL     
..............................................................
..............................................................
..............................................................
```

So, as you can see, into this second table (**TID031_PIANO**) there is the **PRG_INT** field that represent the primary key of the **TID023_INTERVENTO** table.

I know that I can first retrieve the list of the records of the **TID031_PIANO** table by my original simple query, this one:

```
select * from TID023_INTERVENTO where COD_TIP_STA_INT = 2 && COD_TIP_BAN = 2;
```

and then iterate on each record to obtain the primary key and so use this primary key to perform a second simple select query on the  **TID031_PIANO** table specifying the condition on the **PRG_INT** field of this table.

But I want perform it into a single query performina join or something like this.

What is the best way to achieve this task?

Comment: Why don't you use join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are looking for join syntax?

```
select * from TID023_INTERVENTO s
INNER JOIN TID031_PIANO t 
ON(s.PRG_INT = t.PRG_INT )
where s.COD_TIP_STA_INT = 2 and t.COD_TIP_BAN = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    TID023_INTERVENTO t1 
      INNER JOIN TID031_PIANO t2 
      ON (t1.PRG_INT = t2.PRG_INT) 
WHERE 
      COD_TIP_STA_INT = 2 AND COD_TIP_BAN = 2;
```

Comment: yep, you posted same answer as mine

Comment: Actually , I was a bit faster then you:)

Comment: maybe we pressed Enter at the same moment :)